# Why the answer giver overtake my answer?

Tags: discussion, attribution, specific-answer, unaccepted-answer

I have given a very short answer that questioner is satisfied with my answer and up voted and accepted my question and after some time another answer giver steal the idea of mine but very cleverly description of the answer. I know my answer is not so descriptive, but I want to say that answer giver should not hack another answer but give `up vote` to that answer that the first answer giver would not be in the corner he should be in the center of the topic. But he could also answer the question by declaring a suggestion from him.

Comment: In your comment you suggest the OP un-upvoted your answer, but he doesn't have the rep to vote.

Comment: bite em hard so they never dare to do that.. ;)..

Comment: Clearly you misunderstand the whole point of SO. It is not a race that can be / should be _won_ by answering first. It can be a little difficult to digest, especially when you are just getting started. But it is about helping the community get solutions. I'm sure you will forget this incidence and post some great answers in the future. :-)

Comment: I would hardly call what you posted "an answer".

Comment: See user2253835 on that question, you'll find the answer that is specifying about table-cell;

Comment: @Jim You should have noticed that giving table-cell to `"a"` rather than .navbar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using very strong words here - the correct use of CSS is not something that only you can come up with. You are assuming that the other answer wouldn't be possible without yours, but you don't provide any proof.

As for the asker changing their minds and awarding the accept to some other answer - that is their right.

In view of your answer being a single line and a link and the "competing" answer being, well, much much more than that, are you really surprised?

Comment: You can see the edit version of that accepted answer and mine answer. It is very time gapping. about 1 hour.

Comment: No I'm not saying that other answer is not possible without mine but I want to say that he should have declared as my answer and that's all I want to say.

Comment: @user2253835: I don't think you will be satisfied with any answer you get here, so my advice is: Live with it, move on.

Comment: @user2253835 - Actually, the timestamp of the original revision of the "competing" answer is 16 minutes **before** yours, and it is also much more substantive.

Comment: @Felix Yeah! You are right! What I'm saying people are understanding me negatively.

Comment: @Oded but before Edit he has not declared about that table-cell;

Comment: Yes, it was added later. But it is still much more substantive - this person put in much more effort in their answer than you seem to have.

Comment: @Oded but I only want to say that he should have declared my answer. That's all I want to say, I'm not depressed from not accepting my answer but depressed from that answer giver who didn't noticed my answer.

Comment: @user2253835 - Yes, attribution is something we would like to see. But you are assuming the other person didn't come up with the answer by themselves. You can always leave a comment, you know, asking for attribution?

Comment: Yes! I'm surprised about that anyway effortlessly thankin you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the bad guy of the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949288/5640).

I just wanna make you know that in my second question (edited after the OP cleared the specs of the problem, because the first answer would have fit the initial question), I have not stolen anything from your answer (actually, I didn't even read it...), I know CSS2 properties from a bit more than one day.

Furthermore, you didn't provide the solutions to the inner margins (achieved through `border-spacing`) that OP asked, nor suggested the `display: table` on the parent, that [even if not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379561/using-displaytable-cell-without-containing-displaytable), in my humble opinion is more correct.

It's not only about the quality/lenght of the answer (that obviously matter), but also the polishing of the result. Open both yours and mine fiddles, and find the 10 little differences about them.

---

edit

> You should have referenced a little only that I have set display: table-cell; to a rather than .navbar. 
>   That's all I want to say. Anyway, you haven't seen my answer, I'm blind for that.

As said, your solution was uncomplete, and your fiddle did not reproduce the result asked by OP.

I have no problems referencing / upvoting other user's answers (to be honest, Sportmanship badge is likely to arrive at any moment).

[As a proof of good faith, take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275404/html-layout-continuous-images/14275671#14275671): I had the accepted answer, using a (perfectly legal) trick, but after having seen the other user's answer (classic, no workaround involved), I upvoted his answer and suggested through comments that it should have been marked as the accepted answer; when it was clear that it would have not, I edited mine, appending his solution, referencing him, and creating a fiddle because some guys was not able to reproduce the result.

SO is for knowledge sharing, downvoting is for **bad** answers and **bad** questions, not for *punishments*... the button you was looking for was *add a comment*.

Comment: Who removed my initial "Hello World" ? It was a polite 'hi' to this new Community in my first post :)

Comment: I didn't remove it, but we see salutations as noise in posts. It doesn't really add much to the actual question/answer.

Comment: @AndreaLigios You should have referenced a little only that I have set `display: table-cell;` to `a` rather than `.navbar`. That's all I want to say. Anyway, you haven't seen my answer, I'm blind for that.